# Can the area under a mass flow - temperature curve give the total mass?

Tags: mass, integration, flow

I have three systems that release mass at different mass flows and I would like to know which system releases more mass. I have access only to a $\dot{m}$ vs $T$ plot (see below):

[image]

Unfortunately there is no information about the time frame. I only know that the difference between the systems is the geometry (no clear information about it either, just that they are different). I also have the values for the mass flow and temperature.

Is there any way to explain/prove which one releases more mass? Intuitively I would say that s1, because it has the highest peak, but something tells me that I'm wrong because I have no time frame. Any help with this analysis would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the temperature change during, and perhaps as a function of the mass flow? If not, the result is trivially obvious (the system with the higher flow rate releases more mass, of course), but if yes then things depend on how fast the temperature changes in the three cases.

Bottom line, if the above is all the information you have, then the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer... This is all I have, unfortunately.

Comment: You have no information on the temperature of the three systems at all? Perhaps you can assume they're at roughly identical temperatures during the process. That would be good enough to take us back to the first answer. Otherwise, unfortunately you're stuck.

Comment: Well, I know that the results were obtained in a Temperature Programmed Desorption/Mass Spectrometry, but no info about the temperature profiles.